# IT are failing when db type is mongodb and entities have required relationships. IT classes contain references to "EntityManager em"

Tags: jhipster

Steps to Reproduce it:

1- Download apps.jh from https://gist.github.com/mraible/3c97f60c6617e67fd87cd9895d54311c

2- Change db to mongodb.

```
databaseType mongodb,
devDatabaseType mongodb,
prodDatabaseType mongodb,
```

3- Change relationships to required.

```
relationship ManyToOne {
Blog{user(login) required} to User,
Post{blog(name) required} to Blog
}

relationship ManyToMany {
Post{tag(name) required} to Tag{post}
}
```

Output:

Integration Test classes contain references to "EntityManager em"

For Example

Class UserResourceIntTest

```
public static User createEntity() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    user.setLogin(DEFAULT_LOGIN);
    user.setActivated(true);
    user.setEmail(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
    user.setFirstName(DEFAULT_FIRSTNAME);
    user.setLastName(DEFAULT_LASTNAME);
    user.setImageUrl(DEFAULT_IMAGEURL);
    user.setLangKey(DEFAULT_LANGKEY);
    return user;
}
```

and in class BlogResourceIntTest...

```
public static Blog createEntity() {
    Blog blog = new Blog()
        .name(DEFAULT_NAME)
        .handle(DEFAULT_HANDLE);

    // Add required entity
    User user = UserResourceIntTest.createEntity(em);
    em.persist(user);
    em.flush();

    blog.setUser(user);
    return blog;
}
```

Comment: This post looks more like a bug report rather than a question for stackoverflow. Please consider reporting it on https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster with details about your configuration, use `jhipster info`

Comment: Yes, it is a bug report. I will consider reporting it. Thank You.

Comment: For others finding this question, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8519